# simple modal contact form wordpress plugin gives "404 not found" on submit

Tags: forms, jquery-plugins, jquery, simplemodal

I had this simple modal contact form working fine but must have broke it somewhere along the way and can't figure out where. Now when I hit submit I get a **404 Not found**.

In Firefox the 404 message never shows and from the Error Console I'm seeing the following error repeated:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 125"  data: no]

The popup form can be found here at this site in development:

http://dailybutter.com

It's been styled and there are 2 other popups on the home page that also use the smcf plugin "market statistics" and "quick search".

The contact form was working after customizing appearance and adding those 2 other popups so I don't know why it's not now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the action is `null` and it's posting to the wrong page, the plugin is looking for the action here:

```
$('#smcf-content form').attr('action')
```

But your modal looks like this (when opened):

```
<div id="smcf-container" class="simplemodal-container">
 <div id="modal_content1" class="simplemodal-data">
  <div class='smcf-content'> 
   <form action='/wp-content/plugins/simplemodal-contact-form-smcf/smcf_data.php'>
```

That `class='smcf-content'` div needs to have an ID of `id='smcf-content'` instead of a class for the plugin to submit properly, or the plugin just wasn't updated...I see `#smcf-container` everywhere else, so it's possible this one ID selector was just missed and needs to be changed as well.

Comment: thanks for the fast response! used the latter suggestion - changed jquery to look for #smcf-container form and that seems to have solved it.

much appreciated.